# Omit name in cleveref only in specific occasions

Tags: cleveref

In the document I'm working on, in most cases I need `\cref{eq:kolmogorov}` to write, e.g., `Equation (2.4)`. But in some specific cases I only need it to be `(2.4)`, without `Equation`. How can I do this?

EDIT: I could use `\eqref{}`, but the problem is that the parentheses are not coloured with `\eqref`, only the number is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `\eqref{eq:komogorov}`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yes but the problem is that the parentheses are not coloured when using \eqref{}. Is there a way to colour them?

Comment: Maybe `\textcolor{some colour}{\eqref{...}}` (for which you could define a `\myeqref` macro)?

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cleveref` package has the `\labelcref` macro for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
xxx\label{key}
\end{equation}

\cref{key}

\labelcref{key}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that macro. Thanks!